# What processor architectures and operating systems can CIL be interpreted to?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cil

I am creating an online website in ASP.NET with C# scripting. It incorporates a MySQL database.

I have heard that C# is compiled into the Common Intermediate Language (CIL), and is then interpreted on the machine on which the code is run. Does anybody know which processor architectures and operating systems CIL interpreters exist for (this said, I am not actually sure that the .Net framework works on anything other than Windows)?

Comment: Mono: http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET

Comment: Could you mind giving us some background on why you're asking this question? It might help us give you an answered more geared towards what you want to know.

Comment: Hello msm8bball. This program is a project for a Computing A level, it will be an online booking system. There is a section in the documentation for the project where I have to research possible ways of creating a solution - different languages and storage mechanisms which I could use etc. I wanted to see if using C# for the scripting would allow the program to be used on different operating systems (this being an advantage of interpretation), as this is obviously quite important for a booking system.

Comment: I do not understand. Why do you need the system to run on different architectures? Normally you have your web server, and then other people access it (clients). You don't have to care about what architecture other people are using to access it, as they only have to be able to understand HTTP (run a web browser).

Comment: Even though there is a script running behind the webpage? I would have though that this can only be run if there is an interpreter for the operating system and architecture of the user's machine (interpreter which can interpret the CIL into native code).

Comment: @LordCat With ASP.NET, the code for the page runs on the server (though I wouldn't call it an interpreter), it doesn't need any support from the browser. Just like you don't need PHP installed to access pages written in PHP.

Comment: As long as your clients can use a web browser, they can use a site that was made in ASP.NET (or any other server side language/technology).

Comment: Yes, of course! I think I was getting a little confused. The point still stands though; which operating systems and archetectures can CIL be interpreted to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft .Net runs in Windows, x86, x64 and IA64. But there is another implementation called mono with [a broad support for platforms and OS](http://www.mono-project.com/Supported_Platforms):

OS:

> - Linux
> - Mac OS X, iPhone OS
> - Sun Solaris
> - BSD - OpenBSD, FreeBSD, NetBSD
> - Microsoft Windows
> - Nintendo Wii
> - Sony PlayStation 3

Platforms:

> - s390, s390x (32 and 64 bits):    Linux
> - SPARC (32):  Solaris, Linux
> - PowerPC:     Linux, Mac OSX, Wii, PlayStation 3
> - x86  Linux, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD, Microsoft Windows, Solaris, OS X, Android
> - x86-64: AMD64 and EM64T (64 bit):    Linux, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, Solaris, OS X
> - IA64 Itanium2 (64 bit):  Linux
> - ARM: little and big endian:  Linux (both old and new ABI), iPhone, Android
> - Alpha:   not maintained. Linux
> - MIPS:    Linux
> - HPPA:    not maintained Linux

Comment: Windows RT also runs on .Net on ARM, but I believe that's just for Windows Store apps. And there are also versions for Windows Phone (not sure about the CPU) and other embedded devices.

Comment: Microsoft also has .NET Framework for IA64, so you should probably update that row, http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21969